# Flutter/Firebase - How to get "heads up" notification on Android?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter application using the firebase-messaging plugin for push notifications.

I register firebase like normal on the client, and I send the `fcmToken` to the server.

Notifications are created via a python server using `aiofcm` (which uses firebase's XMPP api). They're created like this:

```
message = aiofcm.Message(
    device_token = t2,
    notification = {
        "title":notification_title,
        "body":notification_body,
        "sound":"default",
        "tag":link
    },
    data = {
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    },
    priority=aiofcm.PRIORITY_HIGH
)
await fcm.send_message(message)
```

On iOS, notifications pop-up at the top of the screen.

On Android, only the icon shows up in the notification tray - not any of the notification content. This is tested on a Pixel 3 and a OnePlus 6, both running Android P.

Ideally, I would like the notification to be "heads-up" style like this:

[image]

Before I was able to accomplish this using `data` messages and creating the notification programmatically in native android, however I would like to avoid that if possible since data messages don't get delivered on Android if the app is terminated.

Comment: `notification`-message payloads are automatically handled by the Android device. If the goal is to implement a custom notification, then `data` is the only (current) way to go.

Answer (score 2):

To Get heads-up - Notification - Kindly set "alert: true"

Example :

```
notification = {
    "title":notification_title,
    "body":notification_body,
    "sound":"default",
    "alert" : true
    "tag":link
},
```

Comment: not working, also couldn't find it in the docs

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: it's strange but it started working the next day) but it's working without "alert", maybe because I added "android_channel_id"

Answer (score 1):

For heads up notification you will need to use [flutter_local_notifications Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). It is even recommended in [FlutterFire official documentation for notification](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/) to show notification in foreground (background notification also supported ofcourse!) and it shows heads up notification by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [firebase.flutter.dev](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/) docs it shows how to do this easily with the help of [flutter_local_notifiation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [background fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) and [local notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package for background app running.